Amplify Federated Signin Documentation for Amplify Gen 2?
The Amplify Gen 2 documentation for Federated Signin is "Shorter" than the Generation 1 documentation.
Does anyone know whether there is a setup guide for Federated Signin included with the Amplify Gen 2 documentation that is similar in detail to the Gen 1 documentation?
